# Order by timestamp using MongoDB's _id property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am fairly new to MongoDB, and I know that when adding an element into a Mongo database, it automatically generates an `_id` property on each element you add. I also read that this `_id` has a timestamp built into it. So, my question is, is it possible to sort an array of objects (that all have the `_id` prop) using this timestamp? (Either with a Mongo/mongoose method or plain JavaScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort directly by the `_id` itself and it will bring the documents ordered by their creation date. For that, for example, if you want a descendent order (newest documents first), then:

```js
db.collectionName.find().sort({_id: -1})
```

If you want the other way, just simply change the `-1` for a `1`.

Take into account that the created date used is up to seconds, so documents created within the same second, but with different milliseconds may not be ordered as expected.